# Mock WebRequest getDescription method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, webrequest

I'm working with Spring Boot and Mockito in Java and need to know what the output of WebRequest's getDescription method looks like. I'm trying to mock it as such:

```
WebRequest webRequest = mock(WebRequest.class);
doReturn(??).when(webRequest).getDescription(false); //What is the format of the return?
...
```

Any sample is fine, I just need something valid to output. Thank you!

Comment: The preferred way of writing this is `when(webRequest.getDescription(false)).thenReturn(??)`, then your IDE's code hints (and the compiler) will tell you the type of the return value.

Comment: The documentation for `WebRequest.getDescription()` says that it returns a description and provides no further format requirements. It's a method to return a _human readable_ description of the request. You **shouldn't rely on its format** -- if you are testing that it is logged correctly or appears in an error message, then your mock should return an arbitrary string (a completely random one will do!) and check that it arrived wherever you wanted it to go.